# flutter android tv listview focused item change background and text

Tags: flutter

I'm building a simple app for Android TV with Flutter.

I have a listview of items and would like to change the page background and page text on each focused item without onPressed...

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work with items that need focus, is using the [Focus class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus-class.html).

To do so, you need to set a `FocusScope`, where each of your ListView items are a `Focus` with a `FocusNode` each.

Your widget tree should look like this:

FocusScope --> ListView --> Focus --> Builder (or any widget that can provide a context)

To check if the last widget is focused, you can do it like this:

```
final FocusNode focusNode = Focus.of(context);
final bool hasFocus = focusNode.hasFocus;
```

And so, if hasFocus is true, you change color or TextStyle or whatever you need.

**Edit**

I forgot this.
If you need to change something else (not the focused item) you can use the `onFocusChange` property of the `FocusScope`.

I hope this helps and you can develop your app further!

Comment: Thank you Francesco !    I am getting closer.... so if a have widget with listview each item could be another widget and thats way its easier to check if the widget is focused and just just setstate to change background image ?

Comment: @aknd I just understood that you meant the background of the whole page and not just the focused item. You can use setstate in the onfocuschange property of the FocusScope to do so.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierSnchez Hi DO we Have any example/Reference link. If I add FocusScope above ListView.Builder somehow scrolling is not working